# How to Specifically Check if the SQL Database Has Gotten Opened? - VB.NET 2012 MVC 4

Tags: .net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

```
    Function SQLSelect() As ActionResult

    Dim theconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb);Database=test_drive_database;")
    Dim queryString As String = "SELECT * FROM ColorTable"
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString)
    command.CommandTimeout = 15
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    'Printing Out the SQL Result

    Return ViewData("command")

End Function
```

I am having an empty SQL result, with no error messages.

The URL to invoke the above function is: `http://localhost:1812/Home/SQLSelect`

The question is, is there a way to specifically check if the SQL database has gotten opened?

**The Tools Used:** *Visual Studio 2012, VB.NET MVC 4, Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0*

**Notice:** *The database name is `test_drive_database`, and there is no password set for the database.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are some errors in your code

If you are connecting to a Sql Server Compact then connection string should be something like this

```
  Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

[see ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012)

Then the objects to work with are [SqlCeConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) and [SqlCeCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) from the namespace

```
  System.Data.SqlServerCe
```

Two more problems are: you don't open the connection and don't associate the connection to the command

```
  theconnection.Open
  command.Connection = theconnection
```

Answer (score 1):

As Steve said, you need to invoke the `Open` method of the SQLConnection object to open the connection.

Once you've done that, you can use the `State` property of the `SQLConnection` object to check the status of the connection at any time.

```
    Dim sConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    If sConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Debug.Print("Your database connection is open")
    ElseIf sConn.State = ConnsectionState.Closed Then
        Debug.Print("Your database connection is closed")
    Else
        Debug.Print("Your database connection state: " & sConn.State.ToString)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try
`If (theconnection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then`
   `//your connection is open`

Consider not only the *Open* or *Closed*, but also the *Connecting*, *Broken*, *Executing*  and *Fetching* options.